# Python Astroid (Pylint) How to mimic inheritance when class passes through factory?

Tags: python, metaprogramming, factory-pattern, pylint

Where I work, we extensively use SQLAlchemy. Overtime we developped a base class for our models that fits our needs. But when time comes to lint our code, we are always overwhelmed by warning we know we could ignore. But so far we only managed to do this globally with the `generated-members` directive which tends to hide issues.
So I started to wonder: *“How could I teach that to pylint ?”*

Here is the situation:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

class CustomBaseModel(object):
    def feature(self):
        pass

Model = declarative_base(cls=CustomBaseModel)

class Thing(Model):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    label = Column(String(64))

t = Thing()
t.feature()  # Pylint says Thing has not `feature()` method.
```

So what I'd like to do is tell pylint that Model is in fact, more or less CustomBaseModel.

Hence it looks more like I should use an [`inference_tip`](https://astroid.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extending.html#ast-inference-tip-transforms) on the return value of the call to `declarative_base()`. But I am not exactly sure on how to proceed. And it looks like the API changed over time and I am not going anywhere.

Another strategy I looked into is  copy attributes found on the `CustomBaseModel` to Model. But it does not work. Indeed to Pylint Model seems to just be a name... it lost track of what it is and has no clue that it is a class.

Any hints would be much appreciated...

Comment: I am not an expert in pylint, but I am guessing that you may be able to replace `Model = x(cls=Base)` with something like `@decorator class Model(Base): pass`, where `decorator` is a function that calls x(cls=arg) (or whatever else you need to produce the derived class).

Comment: Definitely not the path I stepped on... but it looks like it works. And it is so much simpler than what I had in mind ! I feel stupid now. But I guess I owe you one Thanks @LeoK !

Comment: I'll add that as an answer, then, just wasn't sure it will work - I don't have pylint setup, so I could not try it easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you replace this:

```
Model = declarative_base(cls=CustomBaseModel)
```

with something like this:

```
def base_decorator(cls):
    return declarative_base(cls = cls)

@base_decorator
class Model(CustomBaseModel):
    pass
```

This will result in something similar to the following sequence of execution:

```
class Model(CustomBaseModel):
    pass
Model = declarative_base(cls = Model)
```

This is functionally the same as the direct call you have in your sample code, but it gives `pylint` a clue that `Model` is derived from `CustomBaseModel`.

Comment: Actually there is a `@as_declarative()` decorator provided by SQLAlchemy. Just use that and you end up in a much better place. Sorry I should have mentionned it before !

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer most relevant to my case and SQLAlchemy in general I would dare to say. Still credits go to LeoK for pointing me in the right direction.

If you rewrite the code like this:

```
from sqlalchemy import as_declarative


@as_declarative
class Model(object):
    # ...
    def feature():
        pass

class Thing(Model):
    pass

t = Thing()
t.feature()  # No more complain !
```

This will result in the exact same `Model` class as before, but without the need for the *go-between* `CustomBaseModel` class.

Since a class decorator is expected to return a class, this is clearer in the intent for Pylint. It no longer looses track of the attributes on the class.

Let's note that, nothing prevents you from completely messing your class with the decorator. Though Pylint can cope with some of it and is not that easy to fool. I guess most meta programming comes in the way though.

Here are some examples to play with:

```
def class_breaker(cls):
   # Try some of those:

   # E: 37, 0: Assigning to function call which only returns None (assignment-from-none)
   # return None  # return None too obvious

   # E: 47,21: BrokenClass is not callable (not-callable)
   # cls = None  # Confuses Pylint a bit. Hard to reconcile the message with the issue (IMHO) but correct.
   # return cls

   # No warnings ! return value is a type
   cls = type('Broken', (cls, ), {})
   return cls


@class_breaker
class ClassToBreak(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self._name = name

    @property
    def name(self):
        """Retrieve the name"""
        return self._name


class OtherClassToBreak(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        """Init."""
        self._name = name

    @property
    def name(self):
        """Retrieve the name"""
        return self._name


BrokenClass = class_breaker(OtherClassToBreak)


def main():
    instance = ClassToBreak(name='foo')
    print instance.name


    other_instance = BrokenClass(name='foo')
    print other_instance.name


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```